# How do I change the font in markdown pandoc?

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I am writing a document in markdown, and I read that I could change the font to Arial like this:

```
---
fontfamily: arev
---
```

But it did not work. But when I try to change the font to Times, it's working fine

```
---
fontfamily: times
---
```

So how do I change the font to Arial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc uses LaTeX per default for PDF generation, so it depends on your TeX installation.

If you're on TeX Live you can use most [in this font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/).

Answer (score 4):

If Helvetica is "good enough" you can use:

```
fontfamily: helvet
header-includes:
  - \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

Comment: This still isn't working. I'm getting a file titled 'missfont.log'. It says  ''mktextfm phvr8t'. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @themthem Which TeX distribution do you use? That font is part of psnfss, a required part of LaTeX.